# Detect changes in Graphics2D object in Java

Tags: java, compare, state, graphics2d

I'm looking for an efficient way to detect any changes to a Graphics2D object between discrete stages of rendering (so that I can optimise by aborting further superfluous stages once the first "no change" is discovered).

Is there a way to compare memory, or perhaps a checksum, or any other way to compare two states in order to identify (or rule out) change?

Comment: Depending on from what context your generating the graphics context, maybe, but I'd be very in efficient. Instead you could maintain a BufferedImage of the state, when you iodate your model, have it determine if any changes occurred and determine if you need to create a new BufferedImage or not.

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer. Could you give a generic example of the BufferedImage solution as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I've actually solved it now, but only because I followed your advice. I'd love to accept an answer, so please provide something as an answer if you can - even if it's just copying and pasting your comment. I'll give it a few days and provide what I did, if not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on from what context your generating the graphics context, maybe, but I'd be very in efficient.

Instead you could maintain a "current state" `BufferedImage`, when you update your model, have it determine if any changes occurred.  If the model was changed, create a temporary `BufferedImage`, re-render this new state and then assign it to the "current state" `BufferedImage`.

Each time you want to render to the screen, simply use the "current state" `BufferedImage`

Comment: Deep debug session, trying not to get distracted ;)